# How to continue test execution after assertion failed?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertions

I know that this question is duplicate one. But I am searching for the result from yesterday. I didn't got any solution for that..
I am using Selenium Webdriver 2.47.1 & TestNG for automation. In my automation script I have 12 set of tests & I am using TestNG Assert method to compare Expected Result & Actual Result. My code format is given below...

```
@Test(priority = 6)
public void TestingeNote1() {
   cd.switchTo().frame("RTop");
   cd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   String TesteNote1 = cd.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]")).getText();
   StringBuffer object1 = new StringBuffer(TesteNote1);
   String ActeNote1 = object1.substring(108);
   String ExpeNote1 = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 4);
   try {
       Assert.assertEquals(ExpeNote1, ActeNote1);
       ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "PASSED");
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
         ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "FAILED");
   }
   cd.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Execution of test script stops once assertion got failed. I want to continue the execution after assertion fail also. I have used Verify() also, It just gives the verify result as passed. But the above test result is Failed one.

Comment: What error are you getting while you try to assert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a try/finally block.

.
.
.

```
    try {
     //use IF condition to match Strings (ExpeNote1, ActeNote1)are equal 
     ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "PASSED");
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {  ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "FAILED");}
     finally {  cd.switchTo().defaultContent();}
```

Comment: I have tried try/finally block also.. After assertion fail test stops there itself. It is not continuing the execution..

Comment: It's worked for me. Thanks a lot..  catch block is not executed while using above code. Excel not updated with FAILED test result for the particular test

Comment: If your problem is to match 2 strings, then just use IF condition, that will solve your problem.

Comment: While using above code I got eclipse output as `Tests run: 12, Failures: 1, Skips: 0`. This was what actually I needed. But in this case excel not updated with any value..

Comment: Reading some blogs i concluded that assertions (hard) will fail Inside any test method, remaining execution of that specific test method will be aborted. Now If you wants to continue remaining test part execution even If assertion fails and also you wants to report assertion failure In testng result report then you can use testng soft assertion method.[link](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/06/soft-assertion-for-selenium-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use soft asserts. It will continue test even after one assertion failed.

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
String ActualErrorMEssage = firstNameerrorXpath.getText;
String ActualErrorMEssage2 = secondNameNameerrorXpath.getText;
softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage2,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
softAssert.assertAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch block with proper exception catcher. For example when you try to catch a normal exception use `exception` in the catch block, if the element is not present in the DOM then use `NoSuchElementException` etc... In your case catch the exception that you are getting in your error console. Here's how -

```
  try {
       Assert.assertEquals(ExpeNote1, ActeNote1);
       ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "PASSED");
   }
   catch(AssertionError e) {
       ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "FAILED");
   }
```

Your execution stops because you are not catching the proper exception that your assert statement throws. I guess you are getting an AssertionError, if not replace the exception type you get from your code above. Hope this helps.

Comment: While using above code Excel got updated with test result as failed. But Eclipse output is `Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Skips: 0`. The test didn't failed. Simply it shows test as Passed

Comment: Right, it doesn't show as failed as you are catching the exception. If you still want it to fail then you can throw a new exception yourself and don't catch it in the catch() block as you need the catch block to be executed.