# Next test case is not getting triggered when current test case got failed using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a testing.xml file as below

```
<suite name="Suite1" parallel="none" thread-count="2" >
<test name="Test1">
    <classes>
           <class name="com.fb.case1" />                      
          <class name="com.fb.case2" />               
      </classes>
</test> 
</suite>
```

And when I execute the above file, the test case "com.fb.case1" is failing because of an element not visible exception (Waited for the element on UI for 40 sec). Because of this failure, the next test case i.e "com.fb.case2" is not triggered.

From the console, I can see that test case com.fb.case1 has failed and displayed as 
report classcom.fb.case1

Comment: You may want to handle your exceptions using a try, catch. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694542/how-to-continue-test-execution-after-assertion-failed Also, you want to report the failures as illustrated in this link http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

Comment: It may depend on your code, which you haven't shown.